# Can I use a 240 15A dedicated breaker for a 1500 watt baseboard heater?

Tags: wiring

My electrician is putting in a bigger electrical panel, and he asked what amp i need 20 or 30 for this 240 dedicated line to a 1500 w baseboard heater that will be installed later. Can’t i just use one 15 amp breaker since nothing else will be on that circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a normal 80% maximum, a 240V circuit at 15A can provide up to 2,880 W and 20A up to 3,840 W. Right now you only need 15A. However, it may make sense to go to 20A as that will allow you double your heating capacity if you need more heat in the future. The key is the wire:

- 15A = 14 AWG or larger
- 20A = 12 AWG or larger
- 30A = 10 AWG or larger

Since most residential circuits (except oven, HVAC, water heater, dryer, EV charger) are 15A or 20A, the 14 AWG and 12 AWG are the "standard" wires and, more importantly (if OK in your area), *cables*. In fact, you can use the a standard 2-wire (plus ground) cable just like you would use for a lighting or ordinary receptacle circuit to power a 240V heater, with the white wire remarked to use as the second hot wire.

The bottom line is *the bottom line*. 10 AWG wire or cable costs a lot more than 12 AWG which costs more (but not *that* much more) than 14 AWG.

So the general safe option is **12 AWG and 20A**.

Answer (score 1):

Your 1500 watt heater will only need 6.25  amps so a 15 amp double pole breaker and #14 AWG wire will be fine. Your electrician might not carry 15 amp breakers but they are very standard.